# How to find the difference between two list that has pairs of values, using python

Tags: python

I have two list

```
list_0 = ((6668, 75.0), (14, 395.0), (6668, 25.0))
list_1 = ((6668, 71.0), (14, 395.0), (6668, 25.0))
```

I am able to use numnpy to find the difference like so

```
list_2 = np.subtract(list_0,list_1)
print(list_2)
```

which returns

```
[[0. 4.]
 [0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]]
```

Ideally, the results would be something like this.

```
[(6668,4)]
```

But I am not sure about the best way to find the difference while keeping the pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the expected output you provided it looks like you only want to keep list elements where the difference of the 2nd sub-element is nonzero. Here's a one-liner:

```py
>>> list_0 = [(6668, 75.0), (14, 395.0), (6668, 25.0)]
>>> list_1 = [(6668, 71.0), (14, 395.0), (6668, 25.0)]
>>> [(x[0], x[1]-y[1]) for x, y in zip(list_0, list_1) if x[1]-y[1]]
[(6668, 4.0)]
```

Comment: You can make it more general like for instance x is different and y is same

Comment: Exactly, what I was looking for thank you! I tried multiple things, this is very creative thank you again!